# How to deploy a flask application as a zipapp?

Tags: flask

I got a problem. I have been requested to deploy a flask application which is a zipapp. I tried `uwsgi -s /tmp/uwsgi.sock -w filename.zip` and it will shows `ImportError: No module named 'XXX'`.